# Comparing SQL queries with current query values

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I compare D1 to D2 and use the result as part of the query.

```
Select A.id,
(Select b.date from b,c where b.id=c.id and c.id = E.id and b = 1) as D1,
(Select b.date from b,c where b.id=c.id and c.id = E.id and b = 2) as D2
from 
A,E
```

I want to get the lower of D1 and D2

```
Select A.id,
CASE 
WHEN D1 >= D2 
THEN D2
WHEN D2 > D1
THEN D1
END
FROM A,E
```

Comment: No join condition?

Comment: Where have you learnt this join syntax? It was made redundant more than twenty years ago. Use explicit ANSI joins instead (i.e. `from b join c on b.id=c.id` and `from a cross join e`) to get the query more readable and less prone to errors.

Comment: Still joins, i.e. cross join.

Comment: This is the problem with old style joins @ThorstenKettner -- the OP thinks there are no joins

Comment: I suppose `b = 1` is `b.b = 1`? Can there be multiple C per E? Can there be multiple B per C and B.b? If so, which of the dates to show then? (Examples like `c.id = e.id` are always hard to grasp, better make this `c.c_id = e.c_id` or `c.e_id = e.e_id` to show how the tables are related.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [LEAST function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions075.htm):

```
SELECT id, LEAST(d1, d2) FROM (
    Select A.id,
    (Select b.date from b,c where b.id=c.id and c.id = E.id and b.id = 1) as d1,
    (Select b.date from b,c where b.id=c.id and c.id = E.id and b.id = 2)) as d2
    from 
    A,E 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want something like this:

```
Select A.id, min(b.date)
from A
cross join b
join c on b.id = c.id
join E on c.id = E.id
where b in (1,2) 
group by A.id
```

Comment: Im not sure why you include colN? that doesnt look relevant on OP question.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - yeah I re-read and saw he wanted the date column.

Comment: Ok, Im not sure if this is the result OP want because not data sample is provided, but very cleaver ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub-select`

```
select id,
       CASE WHEN D1 >= D2 THEN D2 ELSE D1 END
From 
(
/* Your Query */
) A
```

Start using `JOIN` syntax instead of old style comma separated join. Here is the correct way to do this

```
SELECT A.id,
       D1,
       D2,
       Least(D1, D2)
FROM   A CROSS JOIN E
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Max(CASE WHEN b = 1 THEN date END) AS D1,
                         Max(CASE WHEN b = 2 THEN date END) AS D2,
                         E.Id
                  FROM   b
                         INNER JOIN c
                                 ON b.id = c.id
                  WHERE  b IN ( 1, 2 )
                  Group by E.Id) D
              ON c.id = D.id
```